# Why is there white space appearing between two divs that don't have margins?

Tags: html, css

I can't believe I'm even asking this, but apparently Monday morning isn't going well. Why am I getting a space between these two `div` elements?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Hello</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
 <div style="margin:0;padding:0;min-height:200px;background-color:#c00;"></div>
 <div style="margin:0;padding:0;min-height:200px;background-color:#ccc;"><p>Hello</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/B6xHc/)

Comment: what styles are applied to `<p>`?

Comment: entire coded added.  I know its the p tag but why?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/njk96/ - no spaces

Comment: @ZoltanToth, that is because you're using normalized CSS (additional styles are applied that aren't on by default). See [without normalized CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/njk96/1/). The reason why the normalized CSS works is because it sets the `margin` of the `p` element to `0` as I mentioned in my answer below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is due to collapsing margins. In short, the `margin-top` of the `p` element is causing the space between the `div` elements. To fix this, you can set `margin-top` of the `p` element to `0` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/B6xHc/1/)). If you still want space above the text in the `p` element, you can set `padding-top` to something ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/B6xHc/2/)). Alternatively, you can also set the `padding-top` of the `div` to something other than `0`, which will then use *both* the `padding-top` of the `div` and the `margin-top` of the `p` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/B6xHc/4/)). A little hack to avoid collapsing margins and additional space at the top of the `div` is to set a value to `padding-top` that *computes* to `0` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/B6xHc/3/)).

For more information, see the [Collapsing Margins section of the CSS 3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapsing-margins).

Comment: This can happen with elements other than <p> too. <h1>, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to get around this problem by explicitly setting the `display` property of the `div` element to `block` and the `overflow` property to `hidden` along with setting the margins to 0. Paddings shouldn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

Just a guess but it might have something to do with the min-height and the first div being empty.  Remove that?